# How to Update a C# chart control using databinding

Tags: c#, data-binding, charts

I have a C# Chart Control and I data bind it like so.

```
chart.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(xAxis, yAxis);
where xAxis is List<String> and yAxis is List<Double>
```

On another thread xAxis, and yAxis are constantly updated (Multiple calls to .Add())

However the chart does not update unless I call DataBindXY() again, however this seems to cause issue because every once and a while i get

```
 Error: "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."
```

Which at some point causes my program to crash with

```
 Error: "system.reflection.targetinvocationexception' occurred in mscorlib.dll"
```

-Is there something im missing as far as updating? or should I be doing this diffrently, let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add locking or synchronization both in your update method ***and*** your DataBindXY method.  You cannot modify a List and read it at the same time, because operations on Lists are not thread safe.

I'd recommend reading this (or one of the many, many other) introductions on thread synchronization in C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx

EDIT: Here is an example of how to do this:

```
Object lockOnMe = new Object();

... in your Add loop

(int i = 0; i < dacPoints.Count; i += 1) { 
    TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan(0, 0, i + 1); 
    lock (lockOnMe) { 
        presenter.addPoint(span.ToString(), dacPoints[i]); 
    } 
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200); 
}

... when calling DataBindXY()

lock (lockOnMe) {
    // Note that I copy the lists here.  
    // This is because calling DataBindXY is not necessarily a serial, 
    // blocking operation, and you don't want the UI thread touching 
    // these lists later on after we exit the lock
    chart.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(xAxis.ToList(), yAxis.ToList());
}
```

Comment: Ok, I will do that. I'll Let you know if I figure it out afterwards =)

Comment: So I added

            for (int i = 0; i < dacPoints.Count; i += 1)
            {
                TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan(0, 0, i + 1);
                lock (xAxisRecent)
                {
                    lock (yAxisRecent)
                    {
                        presenter.addPoint(span.ToString(), dacPoints[i]);
                    }
                }
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
            }

as well as the same locks around where I call DataBindXY and I still get the invoction exception =(

Comment: As I pointed out in my answer, you need to lock in both threads- the one that adds the data points, and the one that calls DataBindXY.  My recommendation would be to have one lock, not two.  I'll update my answer to attempt to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

The chart control reads the datasource once (when you issue the DataBindXY call) which is the reason why it is not updating when you modify the collection.

The reason you are getting the occasional issue is because your background thread doing the update is changing the collection as the chart is reading from it.

You may be better off having the chart axis as an ObservableCollection created on your UI thread. You can then respond to the CollectionChanged event to instruct the Chart to DataBindXY.

HOWEVER, in order to use this correctly, your background threads will need to invoke the add calls to the collection on the UI thread. If you have a reference to the chartcontrol you can use the control.BeginInvoke call.

Comment: im slightly confused i tried

     public delegate void InvokeDelegateString(string val);
        chart.BeginInvoke(new InvokeDelegateString(xAxisOb.Add, "ONE"));

Comment: try something like `chart.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=>xAxisObj.Add("ONE")));`